# ¿Cómo puedo extraer la hora minutos y segundos de un string usando la función substring en xpath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xquery

Hola tengo la siguiente expresión pero solo me saca la fecha, me gustaría saber como poder utilizar la función sub substring y extraer solo las horas minutos y segundos.

Gracias de antemano!

```
<chats>
<chat id="CH001" tipo="C" contacto="CTO004">
  <msgs>
    <msg id="M001001" ts="2021-03-01T15:20:23" tipo="texto" contacto="CTO004">Hola</msg>
    <msg id="M001002" ts="2021-03-01T15:28:38" tipo="texto">Hey, perdona estaba despistado</msg>
  </msgs>
</chat>
<chat id="CH002" tipo="C" contacto="CTO002" silenciado="2021-07-15">
  <msgs>
    <msg id="M002001" ts="2021-03-01T11:12:31" tipo="texto">Oye</msg>
    <msg id="M002002" ts="2021-03-01T11:12:38" tipo="texto" contacto="CTO002">Dime</msg>
    <msg id="M002003" ts="2021-03-01T11:12:42" tipo="texto">Tengo que contarte algo, mejor por audio...</msg>
    <msg id="M002004" ts="2021-03-01T11:13:02" tipo="audio" media="https://media.guasap.es?tkn=445ac65e657f515b" dura="45"/>
    <msg id="M002005" ts="2021-03-01T11:14:51" tipo="texto" contacto="CTO002">Vaya tela</msg>
  </msgs>
</chat>
<chat id="CH003" tipo="G" contacto="CTO001" nombre="Brothers">
  <miembros>
    <miembro contacto="CTO003"/>
    <miembro contacto="CTO008"/>
  </miembros>
  <msgs>
    <msg id="M003001" ts="2021-03-01T10:08:01" tipo="texto">Necesito saber quien viene esta mañana</msg>
    <msg id="M003002" ts="2021-03-01T10:12:11" tipo="texto" contacto="CTO008">Yo voy, pero sobre las 13:00</msg>
    <msg id="M003003" ts="2021-03-01T10:12:48" tipo="texto" contacto="CTO003">Yo no puedo, lo siento</msg>
  </msgs>
</chat>
<chat id="CH004" tipo="G" contacto="CTO006" nombre="Amigos">
  <miembros>
    <miembro contacto="CTO005"/>
    <miembro contacto="CTO007"/>
    <miembro contacto="CTO009"/>
  </miembros>
</chat>
```

Consulta xpath

```
/guasap/chats/chat/msgs/msg/@ts/replace(.,'T.*','')
```

Resultado :

1. 2021-03-01
2. 2021-03-01
3. 2021-03-01
4. 2021-03-01
5. 2021-03-01

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el código que has intentado?

Comment: si claro dame un segundo

Comment: Invierte la posición de la T: `'.*T'`.

Comment: genial funciona perfecto, pero también me interesa aprenderlo hacer con substring !

Comment: @Sal, te aliento a que crees una respuesta detallando el porque.